# Change one cell in a database row in Android

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

In my android application I have this table in my database to store data from the user:

```
tbl_Persons

| _id | Name | First Name | Place | ZIP |
-----------------------------------------
```

Now I want to change the `Place` from one line (let's say where `_id = 5`) in the Database - all other cells in this cell should be the same after the command only the `Place` should change. How can I do this in Android? I tried with:

```
ContentValues werte = new ContentValues();
werte.put("_id", 5);
werte.put("Place", "Berlin");

long id = db.replace("tbl_Persons", null, werte);
```

But this does not work. `db.replace` returns `-1` and the android developer site says:

> Returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

How can I only change one cell in a database row in Android?

Comment: You shoulnd't **put** the _id, you should use it in the WHERE clause. Something like `"UPDATE tbl_Persons SET Place = 'Berlin' WHERE _id = 5"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
db.update(tbl_Persons, werte, "_id" + "=?",5);
```

And make sure you have a writeable instance of the sqlite database as here

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```